# Send multiple SMS on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I am able to send a single SMS on BlackBerry, but when I try to send more than one SMS, only the first is sent.

Comment: this looks more like a superuser.com question, than a stack overflow question

Comment: Are you asking by programatically?

Comment: yes i am asking it programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK
you can send sms to multiple numbers using loop.

you have the code to send single sms,

```
for (int i = 0; i < mobileNumbers.length; i++) {

            //method for sending single sms
            sendSMS(mobileNumbers[i],msg);
        }
```

Comment: I have tried it using loop but message is sent to only first number.

Comment: I have post thread to bb forum.the link is http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Help-for-sending-multiple-sms/m-p/633428#M131498

Comment: you have left empty some of the catch blocks.
I think code is throwing exception.

Comment: no application is not sending any exception as i have tried it using system console,then i have removed all the code for exceptions.

Comment: please visit this link i have same issue http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Issue-with-sending-SMS-programmatically-for-multiple-recipients/m-p/600756#M124853

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use MultipartMessage to send large messages.